# Silent redirection not working with mod_rewrite

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to grasp apache mod_rewrite

When I add this to my .htaccess it silently (url doesnt change) shows page bob.htm

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index.htm bob.htm
```

I.e. If I type this in the browser address: `http://mydomain/test/index.htm`,
I get the content for page: `http://mydomain/test/bob.htm`

However if I change the .htaccess to use the full path ...

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule index.htm http://mydomain/test/bob.htm
```

It redirects, but not silently. Can someone explain what's going on please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using relative paths Apache performs an internal rewrite (eg. index.htm becomes bob.htm). When using complete paths Apache performs an external redirect (eg. the url changes).